# Разбиение количества записей из mysql на несколько циклов обработки

Tags: php, mysql

Из БД выбираются поля, которые содержат id номера отеля(`id_hotel_number`). Например выбирается 5 записей, из них 2 поля `id_hotel_number` == 103 и 3 поля `id_hotel_number` == 104.

Т.к. имеется два разных `id_hotel_number` - должно быть два цикла обработки данных. Т.е. обрабатывается `id_hotel_number` == 103, затем `id_hotel_number` == 104. Разных `id_hotel_number` может быть неограниченное кол-во.

Я примерно представляю себе это так: определяем что имеется 2 `id_hotel_number` == 103 и выполнили цикл обработки с `id_hotel_number` == 103, проверяем! Ага, ещё имеется `id_hotel_number` == 104 - значит делаем ещё один цикл обработки полученных полей с `id_hotel_number` == 104.

А вот как ОПРЕДЕЛИТЬ что разных `id_hotel_number` у нас имеется два? И с помощью чего проще решить эту задачу: mysql или PHP?

**Добавлено из комментария.**

Вот код.

```
while ($myrowDate = mysql_fetch_array($resultDate)) {    $begSeaArr[] = $myrowDate['begSea']; // начальная дата    $endSeaArr[] = $myrowDate['endSea']; // конечная дата    $id_hotel_numberArr[$myrowDate['id_hotel_number']] = $myrowDate['id_hotel_number']; // ключи}foreach ($id_hotel_numberArr as $keyIdNmb) {    echo $keyIdNmb . "<br>";    foreach ($begSeaArr as $keyBegSea => $begSea) {        echo $begSea . "<br>";    }}
```

Comment: @banderas, Это вопрос на форум [ХэшКод](http://hashcode.ru/).

Answer (score 1):

Если в SQL:

```
SELECT count(*)    FROM <таблица>     GROUP BY id_hotel_number;
```

даст то количество уникальных *id_hotel_number*, которые есть

```
SELECT id_hotel_number    FROM <таблица>     GROUP BY id_hotel_number;
```

даст список из уникальных *id_hotel_number*

Comment: А как сделать это с помощью PHP?

Comment: Точнее код частично реализован, но работает не совсем в нужном направлении.Вместо того, чтобы в первой итерации обработать только id_hotel_number == 103, а во второй итерации только id_hotel_number == 104, в моём скрипте в обеих итерациях обрабатываются сразу вместе и id_hotel_number == 103 и id_hotel_number == 104.Как сделать, чтобы в первой итерации обработать только id_hotel_number == 103, а во второй итерации только id_hotel_number == 104?

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: я запутался.Давай отдельно ТЗ, отдельно то, что есть в виде целого, а не кусков несвязанного кода.